# Can I use a variable to predict the strength of my independent variable, if it's derived from a component of the independent variable?

Tags: multiple-regression, effect-size, confounding

**Context:** To clarify, I'm looking at stigma in mental health. My hypothesis is that people will admit to more mental health symptoms on an online platform rather than on a telephone interview. Participants complete the online questionnaire and then the telephone interview a few months afterwards. So I've computed a variable that is the score on the online questionnaire - the score on the telephone interview.

**Problem:** I now want to explore what factors contribute to this difference in score. I've created a multivariate regression model to look at factors that contribute to the difference in score.

I want to put in the score at $T_1$ as a factor, i.e., those experiencing higher levels of mental health symptoms are more likely to reduce their scores between $T_1$ and $T_2$.

I'm worried however that since the $T_1$ score is indirectly linked to the derived variable (difference in score) that I'll invalidate the regression model by doing so.

**Attempt:** I personally think that inputting it as is (continuous variable) is fine, but some colleagues have had doubts. I also have the option of putting it in as binary (clinical cut off point) or categorical (non-case, sub-threshold and clinical case).

I've tried all three methods and the effects on the effect size (r2) is pretty big (as a continuous variable it predicts .316 of the variance alone, as a binary .216 and as a categorical .242).

**Question:** So, which is appropriate? Can I use it this way?

**Note:**
The $T_1$ variable ranges from 0:72. (SD 14.8).
The derived (independent) variable ranges from -46:54. (SD 10.29).

Comment: IMO it is actually recommended to enter some kind of baselinescore in your model in the case of repeated measurements. This way you 'correct' for baselinescore (those who score high at T1 have more 'options' to go down/have a negative T2-T1 score than those who score low at T1 and vice versa). The big question however is, whether the online and telephone questionnaires are similar measurements (is subtracting the two scores really feasible?) so that you can use them as repeated measures?

Comment: Both the telephone and online questionnaire ask the exact same questions. In the telephone study, they have a sheet to read from for potential responses, which read the same left to right as the online study.

Comment: The problem with a baselinescore in the model is that baseline score reflects mental well-being-the thing I think predicts the difference in the first place!!!

Wouldn't it simply be countered by those that score 0 (i.e. have more 'options' to go up)? There's a larger population of these since it's a left skewed population (as mental health measures almost always are) so any negative T2-T1 potential should be more than adequately buffered by the positive T2-T1 potential.